# source excel workbook opens up during query from access

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerquery

i have an excel file called **master data 1** and **master data 2**, i queried both to an MS access database and did the changes in the database. Now i need to query the resultant access database table to another excel workbook **" final dashboard"**. but when I use power query in excel , **master data 1** and **master data 2** workbook opens up in read-only mode and stays open. even if I close it opens again when I refresh the query. is there any way to solve it ?

I tried my best but I couldn't find a solution. Note: in access, i used the imported linked tables to create a select query.

Comment: so you do **Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("c:\temp\a.accdb")),** and then two other workbook files open with no code in the third file referencing either of those two files?

Comment: yes, But those two excel files are queried to access database